# How to send the custom content type token value in drupal7

Tags: 7, tokens

Hello I try  when some authenticated user is add the content i want to send the notification  another user for approval of the content in the message field i want to send the content page approval link so I am using some default token value from this page [Tokens](https://drupal.org/node/390482#token-content-type)

But the token values are not generated it will be given as token values given it will be printed like '[content-type:edit-url]'not generated as url not working how to fix the issue

Comment: Please use some punctation and formatting. bullet list, maybe? I wanted to edit your question but I'm unsure what you really want.